# jQuery click event not firing first time

Tags: jquery

We just updated to jQuery 1.11 and it seems like that broke some stuff.  This click event fires on the second time but not on the first.  What could be causing this?

```
$('a.quick-view').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('div.category div.info').hide()
        objInfo = $(this).prev('div')
        $.get(jQuery(this).attr('href'), function(strHtml) {
            if (objInfo.html() == '') {
                objInfo.html(strHtml).show()
                intOuterHeight = objInfo.height()
                strMarginTop = '-' + Math.round(intOuterHeight/2 + 48) + 'px'
                objInfo.css('margin-top', strMarginTop)
            } else {
                objInfo.show()
            }
        })
    })
```

Here is the markup:

```
<div data-info="<?= $objPatientIssue->id ?>" class="info"></div>
<a class="icon quick-view" href="/case-assistant/tooltip/issue/<?= $objPatientIssue->id ?>" title="Quick View">V</a>
```

What this does is append a "tooltip" to the anchor tag.  This works the second time but not the first.  So somehow this is bound wrong.  This is, of course, inside document ready.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong markup. It's right now.

Comment: One other note -- $.get fires every time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone.  Show was firing so quickly that it didn't have a chance to load the HTML. Here is the solution:

```
objInfo.show(10, function(){ objInfo.html(strHtml) });
```